# Odd behaviour of pandas DataFrame.sum when column contains string value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, coercion

I have 3 pandas dataframes of survey responses that look exactly the same but are created in different ways:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,'hey'],[7,8,9]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df2.loc[1,2] = 'hey'

df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=range(3))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if (i,j) != (1,2):
            df3.loc[i,j] = i*3 + j + 1
        else:
            df3.loc[i,j] = 'hey'

# df1, df2, df3 look the same as below
   0  1    2
0  1  2    3
1  4  5  hey
2  7  8    9
```

Now, when I take sums along the columns, they all give me the same results.

```
sumcol1 = df1.sum()
sumcol2 = df2.sum()
sumcol3 = df3.sum()

# sumcol1, sumcol2, sumcol3 look the same as below
0    12
1    15
dtype: int64
```

However, when I take sums across the rows, `df3` gives different result compared to `df1` and `df2`.

Furthermore, it seems that when axis=0 the sum of a column that contains strings will not be calculated, whereas when axis=1 all row sums will be calculated with elements belonging to a column with string elements skipped.

```
sumrow1 = df1.sum(axis=1)
sumrow2 = df2.sum(axis=1)
sumrow3 = df3.sum(axis=1)

#sumrow1
0     3
1     9
2    15
dtype: int64

#sumrow2
0     3
1     9
2    15
dtype: int64

#sumrow3
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
dtype: float64
```

I have 3 questions regarding this.

1. What causes the different behaviour between `sumcol1` and `sumrow1`?
2. What causes the different behaviour between `sumrow1` and `sumrow3`?
3. Is there a proper way to get a result that is the same as `sumrow1` with `df3`?

**Added:**

4. Is there a smart way to add only the numerical values while keeping the strings?

   - My current workaround (thanks to jpp's kind answer):

     ```
     df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,'hey'],[7,8,9]])
     df_c = df.copy()
     for col in df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns:
         df_c[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_c[col], errors='coerce')
     df['sum'] = df_c.sum(axis=1)

     #result
        0  1    2   sum
     0  1  2    3   6.0
     1  4  5  hey   9.0
     2  7  8    9  24.0
     ```

I am working with Python 3.6.6, pandas 0.23.4.

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you try `df.apply(func, axis=1)` with both `func = sum` and `np.sum`?

Comment: @smci both give an error ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 1')

Comment: Do you have a legit use case for needing to silently coerce/suppress non-numeric, or is this just curiosity? (Mix categorical with integer? Why not replace 'hey' with np.Nan?) Also, `df1.info()` and `df3.info()` show the dtypes are different on col3. As jpp diagnosed. So `df1.equals(df3)` fails. I imagine there is some other dataframe comparison method that gives more verbosity to pinpoint that it's the different dtypes; UPDATE: [pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df3)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) does.

Comment: @smic Yes, I do have a use case where I need to keep the non-numerical values. `pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal` is really a useful method and thanks for the information!

Comment: well I spent time on researching that answer even after you'd already accepted one. So if you found my answer useful, you are able to upvote it. Also, please tell us what your actual use case is. Feels weird to mix string with numerical, and still expect it to respond as normal to numerical operations.

Comment: @smci I am extracting information from some survey sheets that are filled up in disorganised formats and wish to do some statistics with numbers extracted from contents containing them, while keeping the details of contents which do not contain numbers for reference purpose. I have upvoted your answer and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- The main problem is your construction of `df3` has *all
  three series* with dtype `object`, while `df1` and `df2` have
  `dtype=int` for the first two series.
- Data in Pandas dataframes is organized and stored *by series* [column]. Therefore, type-casting is performed *by series*. Hence the logic for summing across "rows and columns" is necessarily different and not necessarily consistent with regards to mixed types.

To understand what's happening with the first issue, you have to appreciate that Pandas doesn't *continually check* the most appropriate dtype is selected after each operation. This would be prohibitively expensive.

You can check `dtypes` for yourself:

```
print({'df1': df1.dtypes, 'df2': df2.dtypes, 'df3': df3.dtypes})

{'df1': 0     int64
        1     int64
        2    object
      dtype: object,

 'df2': 0     int64
        1     int64
        2    object
      dtype: object,

 'df3': 0    object
        1    object
        2    object
      dtype: object}
```

You can apply conversion selectively to `df3` via an operation which checks if any null values result post-conversion:

```
for col in df3.select_dtypes(['object']).columns:
    col_num = pd.to_numeric(df3[col], errors='coerce')
    if not col_num.isnull().any():  # check if any null values
        df3[col] = col_num          # assign numeric series

print(df3.dtypes)

0     int64
1     int64
2    object
dtype: object
```

You should then see consistent treatment. At this point, it's worth discarding your original `df3`: it's not documented anywhere that continual series type-checking *can* or *should* be applied after each operation.

To disregard non-numeric values when summing across rows or columns you can force conversion via `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,'hey'],[7,8,9]])

col_sum = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum()
row_sum = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(1)

print(col_sum)

0    12.0
1    15.0
2    12.0
dtype: float64

print(row_sum)

0     6.0
1     9.0
2    24.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! With your solution as a hint, I came up with one more question and added it to the post (sorry if it's inappropriate to add questions). I would be grateful if you could take a look!

Comment: Part of this goes to "How to check two dataframes are equal" (by type, name, numerical precision, categorical levels, etc.). There are tons of such existing questions, I've been meaning to clean up and canonicalize them for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Per your question and jpp's diagnosis, the dataframes *looked* the same, but they differed by dtype on column 3.

Here are some comparison methods which reveal the difference:

```
>>> df1.equals(df3)
False # not so useful, doesn't tell you why they differ
```

What you really need is [**`pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) :

```
>>> import pandas.testing
>>> pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df3)

AssertionError: Attributes are different

Attribute "dtype" are different
[left]:  int64
[right]: object
```

**`pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal()`** has the following kitchen-sink of useful args, you can customize whatever you need:

```
check_dtype : bool, default True    
Whether to check the DataFrame dtype is identical.

check_index_type : bool / string {‘equiv’}, default False    
Whether to check the Index class, dtype and inferred_type are identical.

check_column_type : bool / string {‘equiv’}, default False    
Whether to check the columns class, dtype and inferred_type are identical.

check_frame_type : bool, default False    
Whether to check the DataFrame class is identical.

check_less_precise : bool or int, default False    
Specify comparison precision. Only used when check_exact is False. 5 digits (False) or 3 digits (True) after decimal points are compared. If int, then specify the digits to compare

check_names : bool, default True    
Whether to check the Index names attribute.

by_blocks : bool, default False    
Specify how to compare internal data. If False, compare by columns. If True, compare by blocks.

check_exact : bool, default False    
Whether to compare number exactly.

check_datetimelike_compat : bool, default False    
Compare datetime-like which is comparable ignoring dtype.

check_categorical : bool, default True    
Whether to compare internal Categorical exactly.

check_like : bool, default False    
If true, ignore the order of rows & columns
```